# How to do Object Localization only to get bounding box details without classifying the object?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am working on a problem of Object Localization. Since the dataset is different from that ImageNet of COCO, I only to find is there an object in image or not and not the class of that object. How to proceed?

Comment: This becomes simple regression problem, you need to train model to predict `4` points, which represent the box coordinate. Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I only need bounding box coordinates. Images are also very plain and simple containing only a single object.

Answer (score 1):

You can just produce class agnostic bounding box (i.e., just locate where an object without requiring its class) using regression. Instead of producing the box coordinates directly (box-location, width, height), calculating the offset relative to a default box size will provide with better performance. [SSD](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02325) model actually proposes a common bounding box for each class and calculate per class confidence score for that object. You can follow their approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here, i will give you a reason, why it is  good to add classification with `object-detection`.

Including classification ensure that it is learning class specific features. This way, it can well understand the feature space and corresponding `object-localization`. But if you only use `localization` problem, then it may not as accurate.

For example, we have `4 leg` animal. In first case, it will try to understand that its features which differentiate this animal from the other `object`, whose affect also reflect in the localization in a positive way. But in later case, it only focus on regression, which may not understand these features(thin legs, tails etc) and lose those boundries in detection.

Comment: But, The training dataset I am working on did not specify classes of objects, rather only bounding box coordinates.